# Function with attr() function not executing all statements when there are multiple elements on screen created dynamically by a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The function below creates a red dot on the right end of the screen, animate() to move it left and when clicked, its src file should be changed, along with a few other things as you can see below:

```
function spawnEnemy()
{
    $("body").prepend("<img src='red_dot.png' class='enemies' id='enemy' style='left:calc(" + thewidth/2 + "px)'/>");
    $("#enemy").attr("id", "enemy"+i);
    $("#enemy"+i).css({"left" : thewidth+'px', "top" : (randomInt(10,500))+'px'});
    $("#enemy"+i).animate({left :'-400px'}, 20000);
    $("#enemy"+i).click(function()
    {
      var snd = new Audio("laser.mp3");
      snd.play(); //function stops here
      $("#enemy"+i).stop();
      $("#enemy"+i).attr("src","explosion.gif");
      $("#enemy"+i).css({"transform" : "scale(0.11,0.11)"});
      setTimeout(function()
      {
        $('#enemy'+i).hide();
      }, 350);
    });
    i+=1;
  }
```

This function is executed every six seconds. If, however, the element is not clicked before a new element is created, then all of the elements when clicked stop executing at the line where I have placed a comment. I checked the console, and I couldn't find anything of value, although I know that the problem isn't with the ids as they all have different ids in the console, and since I can hear the sound from snd.play() and none of the effects of the statements after snd.play() are seen, I'm sure the problem lies there. This problem is only when multiple elements are created, as they all execute fine if I click the element before six seconds, i.e, before the function is executed again. Also, thewidth is just a pre-defined global var, so it's not related.
I'm very new to jquery, so I apologize if there's something obvious I'm missing.
Edit: Okay, now all the statements aren't executing even if there is only one element on the screen. I'm quite lost.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? Also is it possible for you to create a jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/ if you cannot see any errors in the console.

Comment: @NewToJS Yes, there are none. Relatable username, I must say :p

Comment: The first 2 lines of your function seem strange to me.  Why don't you create the `#enemy` image with `id="enemy[i]"`?  I would suggest something like this instead`$('<img />', {'src': 'red_dot.png', 'className': 'enemies', 'id': 'enemy' + i,  'style': 'left:calc(' + thewidth / 2 + 'px)'}).prependTo($('body'));` - and eliminate the second line.

Comment: The scope of 'i' is outside the click callback function.  Instead of `$("#enemy"+i)`, you can use `$(this)` inside the click callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I see what's happening.  You need to reference enemy with $(this) inside the callback, because i is in the encapsulating scope, which means it can change and break the internal scope of that callback:

While at it, I cleaned up your jQuery code a little to simplify it.

```
function spawnEnemy() {
    $('<img />', {
        id: 'enemy' + i, 
        src: 'red_dot.png', 
        className: 'enemies', 
        style: 'left: ' + thewidth / 2 + 'px; top: ' + randomInt(10,500) + 'px'
    })
    .prependTo($('body'));
    .animate({left :'-400px'}, 20000);
    .click(function() {
        var snd = new Audio("laser.mp3");
        snd.play(); //function stops here
        $(this).stop();
        $(this).attr("src","explosion.gif");
        $(this).css({"transform" : "scale(0.11,0.11)"});
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        }.bind(this), 350);
    });
    i+=1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thanks, but it seems that the $(this).hide() function isn't executing, the rest are, any idea what's the cause of that?

Comment: Updated to `bind(this)` inside the timeout callback, so the context carries through properly. Should work now.

Comment: Yes, it works, just also wanted to know why exactly the scope of i doesn't extend to within .click() actions within functions?

Comment: It's complicated.  Read up on closures - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures - in short, it could have worked if you defined `i` within `spawnEnemy` (and didn't increment it at the end).  But since i is global, and ever-changing, upon click, you're getting the latest `i` value, which is referencing an element that doesn't exist yet.  By referencing `this`, you ensure that you're referencing the instance of the jQuery element you created, which is much cleaner than trying to reference an element by its dynamic id, anyway.